# Alamofire, dyld: Library not loaded:, Reason: no suitable image found. Did find:, not valid for use in

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

When I try to run an app that installs and uses AlamoFire, I get the following crash after the build succeeds.

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
    0x1006e7eb4 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000209, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000209 
    0x1006e7eb9 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x1006e7ebc <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x1006e7ebe <+10>: jae    0x1006e7ec8               ; <+20>
    0x1006e7ec0 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x1006e7ec3 <+15>: jmp    0x1006e63e8               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x1006e7ec8 <+20>: retq   
    0x1006e7ec9 <+21>: nop    
    0x1006e7eca <+22>: nop    
    0x1006e7ecb <+23>: nop
```

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Versions/A/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /Users/scottlydon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TimeFountain-ezxosxusmvqbwafcjpntqcqqdpkl/Build/Products/Debug/TimeFountain.app/Contents/MacOS/TimeFountain
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/scottlydon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TimeFountain-ezxosxusmvqbwafcjpntqcqqdpkl/Build/Products/Debug/TimeFountain.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Versions/A/Alamofire: code signature in (/Users/scottlydon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TimeFountain-ezxosxusmvqbwafcjpntqcqqdpkl/Build/Products/Debug/TimeFountain.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Versions/A/Alamofire) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?)
    /Users/scottlydon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TimeFountain-ezxosxusmvqbwafcjpntqcqqdpkl/Build/Products/Debug/TimeFountain.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Versions/A/Alamofire: code signature in (/Users/scottlydon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TimeFountain-ezxosxusmvqbwafcjpntqcqqdpkl/Build/Products/Debug/TimeFountain.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Versions/A/Alamofire) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?)
```

I don't know why not having an anonymous "image" would crash my app.  My app has my code signing set

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Changing the signing certificate to Development from Sign to Run Locally solved it for me.